# Access system environment variable in AIR?

Tags: windows, flex3, air

How can one access a system environment variable in Flex/AIR (say %appdata%, %userdomain%)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API that you can use to get a environment variable in Flex/AIR applications. You will have to pass these as (commandline?) parameters to your application.