# NativeProcessStartupInfo executable, absolute path

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have to execute some file but I don't know the path. The PATH variable contains the path to this file.
For example, this won't work in case user installs windows to non-standard folder or uses another drive:
`nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cscript.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using environment variables?

The `WINDIR` variable holds the windows directory, default: `C:\Windows\`
The `SYSTEM` variable holds the System32 folder, defaults to `%WINDIR%\system32`

I don't know how to access system variables in Flex, if it is possible. I'll look into it further.

[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784490/access-system-environment-variable-in-air) claims that it's impossible.

[This third party library](http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/docs/AS3-mSys-getEnvironmentVar.htm) appears to support it, but I don't know how.

---

**DOESN'T WORK:**

You should be able to create the path using them, something like `new File("%SYSTEM%\\cscript.exe");`. I haven't tested this. Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll research it further.